# Mounted disk disappears after reboot

Tags: centos, centos7, mount, nvme

I've got a Centos 7 dedicated server with a SSD + a nvme ssd with 400gb. I followed a tutorial to mount + format (as xfs filesystem) the nvme disk so that I could setup my NoSQL databases on that drive. However every time I reboot my server the disk disappears and the mounted folder is empty again.

**What commands I ran to mount the disk:**

```
fdisk -l
```

Returned:

> Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 400.1 GB, 400088457216 bytes, 781422768 sectors
>   Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical):
>   512 bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512
>   bytes
>
> Disk /dev/sda: 275.1 GB, 275064201216 bytes, 537234768 sectors Units =
>   sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
>   bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>   Disk label type: dos Disk identifier: 0x000b09ac
>
> Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
>   /dev/sda1   *        2048     2050047     1024000   83  Linux
>   /dev/sda2         2050048   528844799   263397376   83  Linux
>   /dev/sda3       528844800   537233407     4194304   82  Linux swap /
>   Solaris

```
mkfs.xfs /dev/nvme0n1 -f (-f was required after the first time)
mkdir /database
mount /dev/nvme0n1 /database
```

Afterwards it lists the drive when I run `df -h`, but once I restart it also disappears from that list. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this to /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/nvme0n1 /database xfs defaults 0 0
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Can you explain why that's needed? I don't understand what the command does

Comment: When you mount a device on the command line, it is only persistent for that session, the nature of it is not stored anywhere.  By placing the entry in /etc/fstab, this file is read at boot time, and ensures your device(s) are mounted on system start-up.  For this reason, be VERY careful when editing this file, don't touch any of the existing content.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to mount a disk permanently.
Doing this will mount your disk during boot time.

0. Attach your disk manually once.
1. Goto `/proc/mounts` and `/etc/mtab` and look for your mount entry.
2. Copy the entry that you want to be mounted on boot.
3. Paste it at the end of `/etc/fstab`. `/etc/fstab` Contains entries that are mounted during boot.

You can even manually add your entry in `/etc/fstab`, but copying it from `/proc/mounts` or `/etc/mtab` makes sure that you not make any error or mistake in listing your mount point

more helpful links [link 1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24182/how-to-get-the-complete-and-exact-list-of-mounted-filesystems-in-linux)     [link 2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218859/permanently-mount-reboot-currently-stops)

Comment: However when using `systemd` everything might be different ("mount units"). Maybe also read about option `-a` in "man 8 mount".